# Cannot create create a new system with a RAID1 partition for /

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, system-installation, raid

I am creating a brand new 18.04 LTS Server system.
I have 2 x 240GB SSD's that I want to RAID1 together.
I have created the partitions I want on each disk:

- 512MB for EFI,
- 16000MB for SWAP,
- 207.436GB for `/`

I have created md0 as a RAID1 using the 207.436GB partitions.

I am happy and ready to proceed... but I can't click <kbd>Done</kbd> and I see no explanation of what I am getting wrong.

I would happily delete the EFI Partitions but I am not allowed to delete just one partition.

Help, please! <kbd>Done</kbd> is "greyed out" for no obvious reason.

[Cannot click "Done" in Partitioner 18.04 LTS Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4zXh.jpg)

Comment: Maybe designate one EFI partition as ESP?

Comment: Thanks for this. My options for the format of the 512MB partitions are:

Leave formatted as VFAT; - - -; ext4; xfs; btrfs; - - -; swap
  
So, I don't seem to be able to designate one as an EFI partition. (I have already copied an EFI partition into that space from an 18.04 Live CD)

Comment: How you boot the install media is how your install is done - maybe you booted in legacy? Or disk partitioning is gpt and you have no bios-grub flagged , 2M unformatted partition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help folks. I faced 2 problems:
a. The installer will not allow the creation of a RAID array without using the whole disk, and
b. The installer would not allow the use of a RAID array to boot from.
Linux itself might allow these options, but the installer did not.
So, I installed a 30GB SSD, put 8GB aside for swap, used the 240GB x 2 as MD0